# How to know the type of uploaded file in React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure

I use the [react app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-browser-file-upload-storage-blob) for uploading files to azure, but I want to know the type of file and then based on the type of file I want to upload to a specific container, e.g., if the user browses an image when user clicks on "upload" the file will upload to "container A", while if the file is video the file will upload to "container B". Therefore, I need to know what is the type of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-browser-file-upload-storage-blob/blob/de78b3bbf6af30b1c40c05ebcee3e8133fa6bfd2/src/App.tsx#L22) you can add below code to get file name and extension.

```
var files = event.target.files
var filename = files[0].name
var extension = files[0].type
```

In the type you will find the extension for eg: if it is jpeg image then,

```
extension = image/jpeg
```

or if pdf then,

```
extension = application/pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, would you please advise me how can I provide if command for the file, because even I wrote

<div>
      <h2>extension</h2>
</div>

to see the value of extension but there is not printing on the page which is loaded in my localhost:3000

Comment: You need to create a state variable to store the extension in state and then you can use the value to display extension.

Add on line 12
const [extension, setExtension] = useState<string>("");

Change line var extension = files[0].type
to  setExtension(files[0].type)

Then add curly brackets as below
<div> <h2>{extension}</h2> </div>

Comment: Thanks a lot,
Would you please advise me about if statement checking, for example I wrote the below code but it does not work:

if(extension == 'image/png')(
    <h2>GameOn</h2>
  )

Thanks

Comment: the container name is determined in "azure-storage-blob", while I get the type of file in "App.tex", how can I provide if statement in "azure-storage-blob" from information that I get in"App.tex"....Thanks

Comment: You need to provide your code for such questions. Upload it to some online tools like codesandbox or codepen